# SQL Update if null add 1 otherwise add 1 to current value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that is updating a field in my table. It could be the case that that column to be updated can be `NULL` if that's the case i'd like to add `1` to that cell. Otherwise i'd like to add `1` to the current value of that field.

```
UPDATE SET Scheduled = Scheduled + 1
```

Would work except when cell's have `NULL` as their value, it does not add the `1` value.

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this.

```
UPDATE table SET Scheduled = ISNULL(Scheduled,0) + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET Scheduled = CASE WHEN Scheduled IS NULL THEN 1
                     ELSE Scheduled + 1
                END
WHERE ...;
```

Answer (score 3):

Although you can easily do this in the `update`:

```
update t
    set scheduled = coalesce(scheduled + 1, 1)
    where . . .;
```

I would suggest removing the need for it, by defaulting the value to 0.  I suspect that will make sense in your context.  If you have data in the table:

```
update t
    set scheduled = 0
    where scheduled is null;

alter table t alter scheduled int not null default 0;
```

(Note:  You can also use `with values` in the alter, but the `update` clearly shows the intent.)

Answer (score 0):

Update yourTable set yourColumn=(coalesce(yourColumn,0)+1)

Or you can use

Update yourTable set yourColumn=(nullif(yourColumn,0)+1)